# Codewars SIGSEGV 11 on a correct program?

Tags: c, string, memory-leaks, segmentation-fault, clang

I'm trying to solve this problem https://www.codewars.com/kata/55c6126177c9441a570000cc/train/c .
I've checked this program with the same compiler(clang-8) on ubuntu 18.04, everything works perfectly, also valgrind doesn't show any memory leaks or invalid read/write at all. But when i press attempt on codewars it shows that all tests are succefully passed but then it says :
"Test Crashed
Caught unexpected signal: SIGSEGV (11). Invalid memory access."
Idk what else i can do to fix this problem, it has good rating and a lot of solutions, but it simply doesn't work for me for some reason. Here's the complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
  size_t cap;
  double rate;
  size_t cnt;
  char** list;
  size_t* len;
  size_t* sum;
} w_list;

void wl_const(w_list* l)
{
  l->cap = 10; l->rate = 2.0; l->cnt = 0;
  l->list = calloc(l->cap, sizeof(char*));
  l->len = calloc(l->cap, sizeof(size_t));
  l->sum = calloc(l->cap, sizeof(size_t));
}

void wl_dest(w_list* l)
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < l->cnt; i++)
    free(l->list[i]);
  free(l->list); l->list = NULL;
  free(l->len); l->len = NULL;
  free(l->sum); l->sum = NULL;
}

void wl_add(w_list* l, char* wgt)
{
  if (l->cnt == l->cap)
  {
    l->list = realloc(l->list, l->cap *= l->rate);
    l->len = realloc(l->len, l->cap *= l->rate);
    l->sum = realloc(l->sum, l->cap *= l->rate);
  }
  //add len
  l->len[l->cnt] = strlen(wgt);
  //add weight
  l->list[l->cnt] = calloc(strlen(wgt)+1, sizeof(char));
  strcpy(l->list[l->cnt], wgt);
  //add sum
  for (size_t j = 0; j < l->len[l->cnt]; j++)
    l->sum[l->cnt] += (size_t)(l->list[l->cnt][j] - '0');

  l->cnt++;
}

void swap_lu(size_t* a, size_t* b)
{
  size_t temp = *a;
  *a = *b;
  *b = temp;
}
void swap_str(char** a, char** b)
{
  char* temp = *a;
  *a = *b;
  *b = temp;
}

void bubble_sort(w_list* l)
{
  size_t* list = l->sum;
  size_t n = l->cnt;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
  {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++)
    {
      if (list[j] > list[j+1])
      {
        swap_lu(&list[j], &list[j+1]);
        swap_str( &l->list[j], &l->list[j+1] );
      }
      else if (list[j] == list[j+1])
      {
        int cmp = strcmp(l->list[j], l->list[j+1]);
        if (cmp > 0)
        {
          swap_lu(&list[j], &list[j+1]);
          swap_str( &l->list[j], &l->list[j+1] );
        }

      }
    }
  }
}

void wl_print_sum(w_list l)
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < l.cnt; i++)
  {
    printf("%zu ", l.sum[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}
void wl_print_list(w_list l)
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < l.cnt; i++)
  {
    printf("%s ", l.list[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}

char* get_res(w_list l)
{
  size_t len_sum = 0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < l.cnt; i++)
    len_sum += l.len[i]+1;
  char* res = calloc(len_sum, sizeof(char));

  for (size_t i = 0; i < l.cnt-1; i++)
  {
    strcat(res, l.list[i]);
    res[strlen(res)] = '\0';
    strcat(res, " ");
  }
  strcat(res, l.list[l.cnt-1]);
  res[strlen(res)] = '\0';
  printf("len_sum = %zu, act_len = %zu\n", len_sum, strlen(res)+1);
  return res;
}

char* orderWeight(const char* s)
{
  char* ss = calloc(strlen(s)+1, sizeof(char));
  ss = strcpy(ss, s);

  w_list l; wl_const(&l);

  printf("A---------\n");
  for ( char* tk = strtok(ss, " "); tk; tk = strtok(NULL, " ") )
  {
    printf("tk : %s\n", tk);
    wl_add(&l, tk);
    printf("l  : %s\n", l.list[l.cnt-1]);
  }

  printf("Before sort---------\n");
  wl_print_sum(l);
  wl_print_list(l);

  bubble_sort(&l);
  printf("After sort---------\n");
  wl_print_sum(l);
  wl_print_list(l);
  //char* res_t = calloc(1,1);
  char* res = get_res(l);
  printf("res: %s\n", res);

  free(ss); ss = NULL;
  wl_dest(&l);
  return res;
  //return res_t;
}
void dotest(const char* str, char* ans)
{
    char* res = orderWeight(str);
    if ( !strcmp(res, ans) )
        printf("SUCCESS\n");
    free(res); res = NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    dotest((const char*)"103 123 4444 99 2000", "2000 103 123 4444 99");
    dotest((const char*)"2000 10003 1234000 44444444 9999 11 11 22 123", "11 11 2000 10003 22 123 1234000 44444444 9999");
    dotest((const char*)"10003 1234000 44444444 9999 2000 123456789", "2000 10003 1234000 44444444 9999 123456789");

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the output of the program:

```
A---------
tk : 103
l  : 103
tk : 123
l  : 123
tk : 4444
l  : 4444
tk : 99
l  : 99
tk : 2000
l  : 2000
Before sort---------
4 6 16 18 2
103 123 4444 99 2000
After sort---------
2 4 6 16 18
2000 103 123 4444 99
len_sum = 21, act_len = 21
res: 2000 103 123 4444 99
SUCCESS
A---------
tk : 2000
l  : 2000
tk : 10003
l  : 10003
tk : 1234000
l  : 1234000
tk : 44444444
l  : 44444444
tk : 9999
l  : 9999
tk : 11
l  : 11
tk : 11
l  : 11
tk : 22
l  : 22
tk : 123
l  : 123
Before sort---------
2 4 10 32 36 2 2 4 6
2000 10003 1234000 44444444 9999 11 11 22 123
After sort---------
2 2 2 4 4 6 10 32 36
11 11 2000 10003 22 123 1234000 44444444 9999
len_sum = 46, act_len = 46
res: 11 11 2000 10003 22 123 1234000 44444444 9999
SUCCESS
A---------
tk : 10003
l  : 10003
tk : 1234000
l  : 1234000
tk : 44444444
l  : 44444444
tk : 9999
l  : 9999
tk : 2000
l  : 2000
tk : 123456789
l  : 123456789
Before sort---------
4 10 32 36 2 45
10003 1234000 44444444 9999 2000 123456789
After sort---------
2 4 10 32 36 45
2000 10003 1234000 44444444 9999 123456789
len_sum = 43, act_len = 43
res: 2000 10003 1234000 44444444 9999 123456789
SUCCESS
```

[Image of the output on site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4WtW.png)

Comment: Cannot reproduce on any platform, check if none of your array indexes are out of range and check if you don't have any buffer overflows. These kind of problems often happen with off by one errors. And `res[strlen(res)] = '\0';` is totally useless, either `res` is null terminated and then it's not necessary, or it's not null terminated, then it's totally wrong.

Comment: Does the crash occurred with the data you are using for tests? If not, it could come with a corner case input.

Comment: I cannot spot anything obviously wrong, but perhaps one of the calls to `calloc` or `realloc` is returning `NULL`.

Comment: @Damien The platform "codewars" provides a few visible test cases and probably more invisible test cases.

Comment: @Damien i'm not entirely sure that the segfault occurs on those 3 first tests but it definitely looks like that. I've added an image of how it looks on codewars

Comment: If you can't launch it in a debugger since it only crashes on some online compiler, then comment out different parts of `orderWeight` until you've found the cause of the crash.

Comment: By adding some output to `stderr` on the codewars platform, I found this test input: `"3 16 9 38 95 1131268 49455 347464 59544965313 496636983114762 85246814996697"`

Comment: Is `l->cap = 10;` the maximum number of input values?

Comment: @Bodo Thank you very much, you saved me! By using this input you provided i found the problem with the help of Valgrind. The main problem was that i was not multipling the amount of elements by sizeof(char*) and sizeof(size_t) respectively when reallocating. Also i was not initializing l->sum[l->cnt] to zero before using +=.  All the problems were in wl_add function. Could you please tell me how you got that info about next test input? That could be really helpful for solving next problems

Comment: @Bodo oh nvm, just saw your answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

By inserting these two lines

```
  static unsigned int count = 0;
  fprintf(stderr, "%u: %s\n", count++, s);
```

at the beginning og function `orderWeight`, I get this output on `stderr`

```
0: 103 123 4444 99 2000
1: 2000 10003 1234000 44444444 9999 11 11 22 123
2: 10003 1234000 44444444 9999 2000 123456789
3: 3 16 9 38 95 1131268 49455 347464 59544965313 496636983114762 85246814996697
```

I assume the first three input strings correspond to the three "*Test Passed*" messages and the 4th input to the crash.

As I understand the code, the line

```
  l->cap = 10;
```

in function `wl_const` limits the number of input values to 10.

I suggest to calculate this value from the number of spaces in the input string + 1.

As a quick fix I changed the limit to `l->cap = 100;` and found these test input strings:

```
0: 103 123 4444 99 2000
1: 2000 10003 1234000 44444444 9999 11 11 22 123
2: 10003 1234000 44444444 9999 2000 123456789
3: 3 16 9 38 95 1131268 49455 347464 59544965313 496636983114762 85246814996697
4: 71899703 200 6 91 425 4 67407 7 96488 6 4 2 7 31064 9 7920 1 34608557 27 72 18 81
5: 387087 176 351832 100 430372 8 58052 54 175432 120 269974 147 309754 91 404858 67 271476 164 295747 111 40
6: 13538 625 102 6986 14449 13233 2347 9239 12995 15637 7462 4757 8792 18878 11655 15413 6132 5858 18575 
7: 11567 19444 10327 10963 3540 287 14288 3422 19868 15561 13831 15478 16176 13923 4537 12697 7156 
8: 1936 2223 6656 11460 9043 17510 10339 698 12923 16461 8618 13571 17310 2257 13015 9709 
9: 18617 12059 9571 2039 13999 7204 17932 9477 3380 13927 16076 
10: 1083 5023 75 5368 11669 11526 14401 9179 3937 17162 4175 2470 7852 17736 19770 10100 12823 
11: 5383 11440 1538 17016 15541 15527 4221 15545 7077 9663 9472 5225 7803 12617 12310 7868 17975 3979 1466 
12: 15221 7465 13683 1468 9925 1535 19194 9695 13697 12017 1247 19070 5529 4847 16087 3142 2447 2380 18677 
13: 12033 8149 16801 19826 2838 9112 9767 813 15153 13295 17324 12446 761 13079 13904 10676 
14: 13098 2444 10374 7187 3681 9445 14778 8518 7604 17910 10955 9974 18659 2541 4079 
15: 1415 5978 11708 10517 15735 14584 7742 11102 11908 189 
16: 4988 14083 2530 1665 9254 7036 12029 18503 10707 3546 13282 1297 13212 
17: 12243 5258 13996 16846 9328 2876 333 15296 14575 10840 13103 9159 18573 4205 
18: 834 18121 10189 14907 2723 11844 6233 9749 5946 4737 456 11554 91 1743 4767 15417 16048 12087 9413 
19: 1415 14352 15290 18773 10999 8203 13948 2230 8848 18144 5359 9672 16265 15539 4579 18978 9455 
20: 10799 17463 17602 11245 9018 19755 15050 15847 15172 13171 7934 6658 10210 11412 3082 
21: 10185 14071 15765 4134 16291 4613 4350 1650 16347 2687 19251 927 
22: 8707 15864 14526 8242 15538 7843 17250 15293 4965 15169 12537 18126 3104 1267 10408 16578 4339 
23: 6763 18400 13736 12959 14691 422 19371 18404 16759 4130 17655 
24: 7857 8434 15612 4455 16667 11150 14360 15989 8515 19316 13231 1053 19514 16325 2310 9923 12903 6640 
25: 1738 5040 3702 16760 1804 6186 16131 208 2946 2334 19925 4766 10181 8360 
26: 16699 7099 13591 11059 5160 2107 12447 18381 5222 11962 16778 7522 3957 11753 16224 13913 13482 3337 17605 
27: 5131 3792 10517 7401 8800 12841 7326 13556 5095 17748 15997 1794 6919 9589 
28: 12070 13758 9435 10451 18970 1397 7230 8564 7416 1055 6861 1329 16599 10188 1006 
29: 17381 6860 19421 6854 15650 14334 14170 9207 19419 13991 7276 3285 910 
30: 18191 12970 12685 7626 5494 13727 11085 14786 4364 573 15831 11215 3964 12431 3475 4960 1344 
31: 11811 2837 9772 9533 17162 3942 812 16581 19995 8079 19857 906 7006 130 13866 1764 9818 1432 
32: 2975 16208 1917 3538 12040 15194 7492 4471 18659 14514 7877 
33: 6325 10705 11349 17921 7867 17354 18723 6520 17349 6802 8449 18245 15871 8569 14184 17625 459 
34: 15178 3424 13887 17086 9024 5927 12280 18578 12460 13012 13093 337 14589 1490 13104 8011 
35: 3043 7437 18125 9554 4786 6999 75 5104 2870 8635 1360 
36: 11156 19028 17736 14571 12915 14822 5667 914 9174 4246 13364 2186 19401 15764 16766 
37: 8868 6849 293 13974 14276 490 5600 1134 7479 5665 6228 
38: 14290 9650 12897 5447 8679 10633 2090 1594 7527 9819 
39: 16692 14055 17925 18868 13456 13689 17706 16410 4630 6627 16693 
40: 903 19245 6266 2028 6724 11921 10318 19126 8284 19959 12024 15793 10710 4729 17873 14366 
41: 7692 18927 8939 3820 18925 9879 19338 12614 9658 15748 19306 16275 14513 19972 17169 13758 8310 
42: 483 232 13649 1681 8506 15680 13695 4299 6390 18415 4244 2829 12734 11926 1756 3745 17808 681 13614 
43: 15358 3272 14967 16736 19538 9481 18781 18779 3239 7091 48 5784 7313 15759 7456 15809 11440 
44: 2180 19892 3710 6414 2721 16434 413 4468 179 18211 7211 15856 17430 
45: 19118 12398 1378 738 1879 159 19507 7180 7240 1627 12955 16616 19449 2483 14497 10889 5696 16668 12853 
46: 3082 15565 7903 3485 2105 8073 3769 9306 6001 3271 13938 7191 15659 15306 7920 19600 17527 
47: 8853 4767 13189 3880 3455 14710 6353 17943 5599 12039 14611 524 3508 19755 16079 11402 5313 256 1547 
48: 9553 9610 14405 5563 16791 12137 2941 6783 11737 468 16273 2662 7297 11534 
49: 10743 6244 12875 10758 13905 6987 7441 14419 12557 7196 12571 6031 
50: 12817 9640 5715 4442 19240 121 9995 16032 12248 14998 2815 6057 17528 1160 8710 4826 14756 17304 17631 
51: 10180 8389 16967 19229 17892 13459 11786 5088 6030 17808 
52: 18837 7448 5365 5352 8761 7548 17409 4793 19786 12408 
53: 7916 9936 12893 18688 16824 7649 15992 14455 10712 8244 
54: 7679 7473 2808 1138 1332 9959 9230 1212 9609 8068 8650 17036 15482 19473 4585 12891 
55: 6443 5299 15999 14349 15226 8892 15109 14122 18603 11102 8578 9315 19336 15556 19057 8882 437 2267 
56: 10386 11488 11406 2067 1628 2128 19093 17100 1602 5750 9991 7930 12184 17353 
57: 8605 14651 16955 3715 8773 15559 14807 19413 6946 16215 14970 
58: 5097 17469 10333 15291 7855 3893 6697 11984 5511 10888 13149 4683 12480 18890 16736 
59: 13146 14089 8474 3823 8740 5429 7528 19576 3060 4407 18989 9997 
60: 16031 18062 7782 13500 10467 5146 3427 14350 13905 15401 19851 4793 8551 6606 19335 
61: 3343 1818 4731 17422 10282 8544 8235 17773 16063 7811 834 2542 8872 
62: 5227 4904 10955 15072 18394 1423 218 1822 17835 14113 17213 
63: 979 7836 6365 314 19411 9698 2122 4142 9193 14466 12677 19490 12240 10812 7301 13064 13344 16163 5957 
64: 3139 18974 15706 1534 2469 15914 5418 305 12099 4703 64 13068 12530 6419 
65: 14013 18180 17557 228 9445 12024 12895 8935 6336 5779 18298 19390 1195 16533 7419 
66: 19663 6393 19597 1197 8853 15511 8677 9148 9683 13370 9202 2751 7972 17683 18186 1986 17935 17816 2204 
67: 11912 17161 16305 18238 2940 14603 17628 6197 11137 5047 
68: 12872 13502 9686 16131 2355 5198 4808 11493 16943 18168 2767 1766 6141 2523 2025 10189 458 19831 12383 
69: 13815 11616 4134 12053 14546 810 11753 2815 14009 18862 12894 6881 12364 2581 3012 14710 9841 7810 8275 
70: 5978 13105 8540 14181 15618 10555 4370 16066 12458 18815 3895 6273 10431 10092 
71: 7049 12964 12141 9855 6973 11003 2749 15916 5440 7392 18918 2222 17223 8800 10487 4007 
72: 3592 14610 11022 19200 7237 17454 17339 19686 16270 1234 
73: 6701 13388 6348 13741 8424 561 3596 17459 13627 8407 13375 
74: 15790 14365 1279 13013 5237 11756 19083 2078 17411 15765 15162 18683 3002 12616 16022 2688 10958 
75: 10710 17650 14779 19120 13463 3204 1753 19121 663 15370 7528 14029 14427 5390 10466 15696 476 15694 9525 
76: 17762 6936 17386 14996 7691 388 9684 3714 5139 643 3033 
77: 365 17802 19103 13818 3078 856 12939 3732 16217 2539 19823 
78: 9992 10289 8413 12530 8055 10 14151 7889 9008 11537 2885 16689 13987 12560 2475 1198 
79: 7570 1181 15620 7445 284 11510 10513 3203 6521 16307 1492 11122 16130 14198 1114 
80: 4683 13634 16537 4683 7785 6499 15753 1394 9374 12443 17444 4006 
81: 18632 1343 4551 19804 16953 11986 2160 8463 2499 5353 
82: 18797 6835 8169 16999 3106 9273 5491 7779 4980 4101 14525 14827 10590 12350 
83: 2036 6865 15728 8105 3846 16432 9438 8387 18308 8464 373 469 
84: 4934 7884 16036 3731 16782 4205 731 19878 15540 8284 9729 520 14447 6326 15338 5037 749 13622 9136 
85: 9350 19303 11440 7854 10813 1899 6163 1349 4334 8694 339 9259 16568 18437 
86: 15422 2642 15773 17372 18172 6130 7102 765 577 15490 16093 7677 
87: 11787 16803 5906 3209 18178 19408 11053 8991 1308 19278 10331 5632 7972 12732 16953 4541 11169 12006 2035 
88: 7779 19398 16117 15971 8572 16872 16539 4062 15037 4216 2364 8896 3091 
89: 12095 1269 9740 5221 12322 13110 4499 4725 18733 12462 19519 15686 
90: 10688 7692 1100 8633 17534 498 6823 13505 9060 5767 12116 15185 805 16322 19611 
91: 1485 9943 3859 4816 1755 9070 19201 14856 13559 3926 15661 
92: 5518 13419 7158 18268 3184 10321 6902 718 10809 13715 16285 1942 19472 
93: 17117 2349 8868 18800 14103 10344 10815 17952 17222 12560 9094 16423 7416 4725 
94: 5149 12809 7930 18559 19957 6198 1743 10278 15162 4523 3160 10949 
95: 5092 12494 13344 4281 14833 2213 3081 11008 14619 13886 
96: 11841 8518 126 10337 17997 4842 12749 3146 17641 2751 
97: 19670 11011 5510 12021 6174 10023 15171 19185 12894 2335 11679 8310 6606 6513 12585 
98: 17511 7204 7707 8544 1118 16215 8660 11445 14212 15564 6266 19421 13205 9007 1126 14948 2090 6627 6969 
99: 18712 4212 9512 13678 6537 1191 1989 15205 7694 14564 9026 7278 3841 16723 17884 4949 
100: 8616 16384 11295 4181 4722 10716 19448 15791 13904 14396 
101: 2603 1365 8198 1316 5567 17700 17056 12094 963 19035 9371 
102: 15672 18387 17988 19503 17182 15872 6524 14265 6560 4980 5560 10731 9692 18338 10180 5483 12242 4576 
103: 14836 8004 15686 18214 13561 15458 15270 7728 16412 16378 17089 7132 12050 17549 5120 13625 
104: 3064 2221 11068 9614 7191 18690 2418 16873 17028 12588 4428 11343 19226 
105: 8251 7230 7603 6465 792 3061 3807 10582 19463 185 9743 8667 14297 7292 13777 7922
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem was that i was not multipling the amount of elements by sizeof(char*) and sizeof(size_t) respectively when reallocating. Also i was not initializing l->sum[l->cnt] to zero before using +=. All the problems were in wl_add function.
This is how it should look like:

```
void wl_add(w_list* l, char* wgt)
{
  if (l->cnt == l->cap)
  {
    l->list = realloc(l->list, (l->cap *= l->rate) * sizeof(char*));
    l->len = realloc(l->len, (l->cap *= l->rate) * sizeof(size_t));
    l->sum = realloc(l->sum, (l->cap *= l->rate) * sizeof(size_t));
  }
  //add len
  l->len[l->cnt] = strlen(wgt);
  //add weight
  l->list[l->cnt] = calloc(strlen(wgt)+1, sizeof(char));
  strcpy(l->list[l->cnt], wgt);
  //add sum
  l->sum[l->cnt] = 0;
  for (size_t j = 0; j < l->len[l->cnt]; j++)
    l->sum[l->cnt] += (size_t)(l->list[l->cnt][j] - '0');

  l->cnt++;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you don't need to increase `l->cap`?

Comment: @Bodo but i do increase it when i reallocate, there is a *= operator. 10 if just an initial capacity which will then grow twice as big every time it's exceeded.

Comment: Using `*=` inside a function argument is confusing. Your code would increase the value 3 times and use different values for the `realloc` calls. Instead of trying to optimize the code you should make it as clear as possible..